# Find term with asterisk *

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a *big* string with html:

```
$html = '...hello{"text":"52"},{"text":" watching"}world...';
```

I want to search in `$html` with:

```
{"text":"*"},{"text":" watching"}
```

So I can *get* the number (where the asterisk is)? In my example, it is `52`, but it can be any number.

I should end up with `$number` equal `52`. Is regex the appropriate route?

Comment: Is it possible that your `$html` variable actually contains JSON rather than HTML?

Comment: No, it is HTML with some random JSON code in there.

Comment: Question: Is regex the appropriate route? Answer: Yes 

Comment: Alright... My concern was that you may be trying to write your own regex-based parser to process data formats that PHP supports out of the box. Is that JSON really scattered in the middle of nowhere? Aren't there further clues that may help you isolate it? The risk of a simple regex is that it can easily render false positives.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am scraping the HTML of a youtube page, [example](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnOTVWVaIh3NoJsbwq4Tucg).

Comment: So you basically need to get `<script>` tags from HTML and parse objects from JavaScript code. Doesn't YouTube have APIs and stuff?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález This is only an example to illustrate this issue. YouTube is not the primary domain. :)

Comment: With absolutely no context at all I can suggest is something like `"text":"(\d+)"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JtvByR/1)). It will work or fail miserably, depending on the season and moon phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `(?<=\{"text":")(\d+)(?="\},\{"text":" watching"\})`

With:

- `(?<=\{"text":")`: the positive lookbehind you're looking for (belongs to `{"text":"`)
- `(\d+)`: the digits you need (belongs to `*`)
- `(?="\},\{"text":" watching"\})`: the positive lookahead you're looking for (belongs to `"},{"text":" watching"}`)

https://regex101.com/r/5eqI2e/1